# How to find the extension for a file that doesn't have one

Tags: php, file-io, mime-types, filepicker.io

I"m using [InkFilePicker](http://inkfilepicker.com) to allow my website users to upload **Images** through my site. Ink uploads it to my Amazon S3 bucket (bless them!) and returns a URL after the upload is complete. Problem is, I want those images stored on my server instead!

OK, so the URL I get back from Ink looks like this:

```
https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JNJB5DkqR8C4OAbzXh8z
```

Yup, no file extension. Pfft .. I'll need to figure out the original file type for this image so that I can assign it a file extension when I save it to my server.

But HOW? It's displayed properly in my browser - so there must be a way!

Comment: You should never trust file extensions.

Comment: You could possibly take a look at Apache Tika, which can analyze the content of almost any kind of file and tell you what it is. I've only used it in a Java context though, and it might be a sledgehammer to crack a nut in this instance. http://tika.apache.org/

Comment: look at the [documentation:](https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#store)

Comment: @HenryW thanks, but client side info can cause indigestion on the server right? Still need to verify it somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PHP [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function

Like this:

```
$img = getimagesize('https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/JNJB5DkqR8C4OAbzXh8z');

echo $img['mime']; // image/png
```

If you want to just extract the extension without MIME Type. You can use [`image_type_to_extension`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-extension.php)

```
echo image_type_to_extension($img[2]); // .png
```

Comment: MIME type isn't an extension.

Comment: You can use `image_type_to_extension` on `$img[2]` to get an extension.

Comment: @Barmar I'm just targetting that extension is there. Edited

Comment: `image/png` is not a valid extension, you can't have `/` in filenames because it's the directory delimiter.

Comment: @Barmar I mean by _extension is there_ was `png` is there :). I'm not saying `image/png` is an extension.